# Must I persist Activity data when onStop() fires?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I find the official documentation regarding the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) unclear. It's littered with words such as *should* and *might* which makes me wonder what I *must*. When it comes to the onStop()-method, the documentation says the following:

> Note: Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped, it's possible that you don't need to implement the onStop() and onRestart() (or even onStart() methods at all.

It's *possible*? Do I or do I not? Lets say I have some custom components that rely on some standard Java objects defined as private variables in the Activity class. Do I need to persist these objects in the onStop-method? Can I be *guaranteed* that these variables have the same content when on onRestart() fires?

edit: [link to table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) referred to in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific question, you need to consider the *killable* column in the overview table. Android (pre-Honeycomb) considers your Activity killable after onPause() has been called. So if you need persistence for the next call, and you want to handle that on the Activity level, that's where you save your activity state.

Comment: What's different in honeycomb+ in this regard?

Comment: @Nilzor Please refer to the table with the _Killable?_ column under _Activity Lifecycle_ in the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html); it has all the information you need, unless I don't understand you right.

Comment: I understand, I was just refering to your comment "pre-Honeycomb" and wondered in what way the Android behaviour changed with regard to onPause post-Honecomb

Comment: I would also like to add to the answer that since Android MIGHT kill the application after onPause, the documentation should rather be worded that all developer MUST persist their vital data in this phase. I can't imagine how many apps in the store have bugs because of this sloppy wording.

Comment: @Nilzor The only difference is that Honeycomb and later may kill your app only after having called `onStop()` while pre-Honeycomb may already kill your app after a call to `onPause()`.

Comment: @Nilzor I basically agree, although there are many apps which don't need this kind of persistence. E.g. there are apps which store relevant information immediately; others don't need much persisntece at all. And judging from what I read here, I'm willing to bet that the majority of apps must have severe problems regarding waste of resources and problems with config changes etc, although most of these problems will rarely be visible to the user (other than with poor performance, but it can't be long until we see the first eight-core processor, right? ;)